# Post complex ajax to MVC controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to save a scene created in a browser using Ajax. The data structure is pretty simple. Primary object is `Scene` and child objects are type of `SceneObject`.

Here is my `Scene` model class:

```
public class Scene
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; };
    public virtual ICollection<SceneItem> sceneItems { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my `SceneItem` model class:

```
public class SceneItem 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public float size { get; set;}
    public int sceneId { get; set; }
    virtual public Scene scene { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Ajax code:

```
    var scene ={
                    sceneItems:[ {
                        id: 0,
                        name: "test1",
                        size: 0.35,
                        sceneID: 1
                    },
                    {
                        id: 0,
                        name: "test2",
                        size: 0.65,
                        sceneID: 1
                    }]
                }
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/scene/create",
                    data: scene
                }).done(function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
```

When I execute this Ajax call, in my debug window of the ASP.NET MVC app, I can see all fields are populated except

```
virtual public Scene scene { get; set; }
```

from my `SceneItem` model. And that makes the `ModelState.IsValid` return false in my controller.

What can I do to make this work in a way that I can post a `Scene` object along side many `SceneItem` objects in a single AJAX command and pass `ModelState.IsValid` and save it into my database using Entity Framework ?

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Well, your `Scene` model class has two required fields - `Id` and `Name` - and you're not providing either one of those in your data structure for your Ajax call ....

Answer (score 0):

add a required field name to your ajax json

```
var scene ={
             id: 0,
             name="name",
             sceneItems:[ 
              ... your data
              ]
            }
```